# Switch off DispatcherServlet on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I disable the DispatcherServlet on SpringBoot, even trying to disable it via servlet registration the uri mapping appears on the log:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
    final ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet);
    servletRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);

    return servletRegistrationBean;
}
```

LOG

```
2015-06-10 10:39:57.552  INFO 7032 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Servlet dispatcherServlet was not registered (disabled)
2015-06-10 10:39:57.553  INFO 7032 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
```

Thanks any help!

Comment: Why do you want to disable it...

Comment: I will use "SpringVaadinServlet" for my application, so I do not need Spring MVC

Comment: Simply exclude the `spring-webmvc` dependency, or exclude the `DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration` in the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation.

Comment: Actually I am using@SpringBootApplication, should I exclude in here? @SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class })

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I added below code into my main class, and the servlet was removed from log.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Answer (score 6):

From Spring boot docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-switch-off-the-spring-mvc-dispatcherservlet)

> Spring Boot wants to serve all content from the root of your application `/` down. If you would rather map your own servlet to that URL you can do it, but of course you may lose some of the other Boot MVC features. To add your own servlet and map it to the root resource just declare a `@Bean` of type `Servlet` and give it the special bean name `dispatcherServlet` (You can also create a bean of a different type with that name if you want to switch it off and not replace it).

Answer (score 0):

If you exclude  `DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class`,
then you need to exclude `ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class` as well, or at least I did.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class, ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class CoreApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CoreApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(CoreApplication.class);
    }
}
```