# Prevent DispatcherServlet from logging endpoint in Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot-actuator

I've turned off the Logging for an actuator endpoint, but DispatcherServlet (and RequestReponseBodyMethodProcessor) still log the mapping and response.

How can i prevent this logging for *just this* one endpoint? I've already turned them off

```
management.logging.level.org.springframework.boot.actuate.health=OFF
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.actuate.health=OFF
org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Logger=OFF
```

but it still comes like this:

```
2020-05-06 17:14:01.545 DEBUG 58588 --- [nio-9095-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/health]
2020-05-06 17:14:01.552 DEBUG 58588 --- [nio-9095-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/health] is: -1
2020-05-06 17:14:01.848 DEBUG 58588 --- [nio-9095-exec-5] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Written [UP {}] as "application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@144409aa]
2020-05-06 17:14:01.849 DEBUG 58588 --- [nio-9095-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2020-05-06 17:14:01.849 DEBUG 58588 --- [nio-9095-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

---

Answer (score 3):

Just set in `application.properties` log level to `WARN`

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor=WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

please check if this solves the issue

In annotation SpringBootApplication add exclude DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration class in main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class })
```

reference :

[Switch off DispatcherServlet on Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758404/switch-off-dispatcherservlet-on-spring-boot/30759963)

Comment: Thanks. I did try this annotation and all my endpoints were unresponsive.But mainly, I am hoping to stop the logging from DispatcherServlet, and RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor for just one endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is logging all the incoming HTTP requests, the solution is not enabling DEBUG logging level in the DispatcherServlet.

You can define a bean of type:

**org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter**

and override the method:

**org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.shouldLog(HttpServletRequest)**

So you can decide which requests are logged or not.
Obviously, you must set the logging level of the filter to DEBUG:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG
```

More info at [Baeldubg site](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging#1-configure-spring-boot-application).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below in the .properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to necro a thread, but here's the answer I came up with:

1. Create a bean as below:

```java
package com.package.your.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Configuration
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfig {
    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter() {
            @Override
            public void beforeRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
                // Don't log any actuator endpoints
                if (!request.getRequestURI().contains("actuator")) {
                    this.logger.debug(message);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
                // Empty because it logs the same content as beforeRequest
            }
        };

        filter.setBeforeMessagePrefix("");
        filter.setBeforeMessageSuffix("");
        filter.setIncludeClientInfo(true);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(true);
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);

        return filter;
    }
}
```

2. Add the following to applications.properties instead of setting DispatcherServlet to debug:

```
logging.level.com.package.your.config.RequestLoggingFilterConfig=debug
```

This works beautifully as intended. Filtering is controlled by the if statement in the beforeRequest method.